# directshow render

Tags: c++, graphics, directshow

hi every one this is my first post here .
i got a misunderstanding of the DirectShow 
the First at all is the render : here is the question if i create a stream where it should appear . should i  create `IVideoWindow * pointerV;`  and create the window form by hand "from scratch" ? because i need to create a sophisticated GUI and *coding it will be mission impossible V*.

i am using VC++ ; i wondering if is it possible to  use  the winFrame directly with all .net 's components and combine the all with directShow functionality ?

Comment: Windows SDK samples could show you the way, did you have a check to check them out?

Comment: Links: [Audio/Video Playback in DirectShow](http://microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625867(v=vs.85).aspx) and [DirectShow Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You just add and connect a Video Renderer filter, it will create the window. Then request IVideoWindow interface from this filter or from the graph object itself (if there is just one video renderer in the graph).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the GUI and render to any component in that GUI .you just have to provide the handle to that GUI element ,So that you can have impossible GUI along with Direct show .

for .Net components i believe the best way is to use .net (say c# .net )you can use direct show wrapper called dshow.net ,it make things very easy since u are using C# and getting the power of Direct show but please note that this will cause come issues occasionally while trying to implement advanced features .But still i think it a great way to use dshow .

but let me suggest another way to use direct show if you are planing to use directshow and have a very complex ui .Use a framework Qt using vc++ compiler .

Sorry i was not able to follow your question properly but hope this helps .